# ¿Es posible linkear una página html a una ventana modal?

Tags: javascript, html

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: tengo una página html en la cual muestra la información hijo de una solicitud padre, entonces necesito un botón "Ver solicitud padre" que al presionarlo me muestre en una ventana modal el formulario con los resultados, ese formulario ya se encuentra listo con sus respectivos js en MuestraFormularioPadre.html entonces para que se entienda un poco mejor
desde muestraformularioHijo.html se presione un botón que muestre en una ventana popup el MuestraFormularioPadre.html.
¿es posible hacerlo? y si es así ¿como puedo hacerlo o linkear el MuestraFormularioPadre.html?
he buscado por la web pero solo encuentro como hacer una ventana modal.
gracias

Comment: Así, a ojo...un iframe, otra manera es cargarlo via XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo haria seria esto:

```js
$('#linkPadre').click(function(event){

  // con esto evitas que se recarge la página al clikear el link 
  event.preventDefault();
  
  //tomas el link del elemento
  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  
  $('#ventanaPadre').css('display','block');
  $('#iframeContent').attr('src',link);



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="plantillaPadre.html" id="linkPadre">Mostrar más</a>

<div id="ventanaPadre" >
  
<iframe src="" id="iframeContent">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</div>
```